# volume shadow copy, used space by folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs, volume-shadow-copy, vss

When creating a volume shadow copy of a drive, e.g. by calling `wmic shadowcopy call create Volume=c:\`, a snapshot of all files is stored in the "System Volume Information" folder.

Older snapshots are deleted automatically, to make room for new snapshots

I can display how much space all file snapshots consume in total: `vssadmin list shadowstorage`
(As far as I understand: if a file does not change between snapshots it does not consume any significant space.)

**Can I display the used space, per file or per folder?**
e.g. I want to know how much shadow storage space is consumed by `c:\path_1\*.*` or `c:\path_2\file.3`, across all snapshots.

The goal is to fine tune shadow storage, by excluding paths with lots of unimportant changes using the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToSnapshot`

Comment: Have you tried vssadmin list shadow storage ?

Comment: @John I did (see third paragraph). it only shows the total space per disk, for all files and all snapshots. If it can show more, I don't see how.

Comment: I have not seen a way to list shadow storage by folder. I will look around some.